# how to choose the best logit model

Tags: regression, logistic, model-selection, regression-strategies

I have two logit regression models with different AIC. I'm using R. my first model has significant variables and AIC 192.7436. And my second model has 1 non-significant variables but with smaller AIC 192.4468. Which model is the best?

Comment: What are the differences between your models ? What is your objective ?

Comment: It is not appropriate to do significance testing to select variables for a model.  See [this](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems).  Don't delete "insignificant" variables.  Pre-specify the model.  Much more detail in [RMS](http://fharrell.com/links).